# Pre-processing multiple text files from a pdf using just pdftotext and sed in a bash script, if possible

Tags: bash, sed, pdftotext

I am using the Linux command `pdftotext -layout *.pdf` to extract text from some pdf files, for data mining. The resultant text files all reside in a single folder, but they need some pre-processing before they can be used.

### Issues

**Issue 1:** The first value of each row in each file that I am trying to access is a barcode, which can be either a 13-digit GTIN code, or a 5-digit PLU code. The problem here is that the GTIN codes are delineated with a single space character, which is hard to replace with a script, as each row also contains a description field which, naturally, also contains single spaces between words. Here I will need to replace a set of 13 numerals plus a space with the same 13 numerals plus two spaces (at least), so that a later stage of the pre-processing can replace all multiple spaces with a tab character.

**Issue 2:** Another problem I am facing with this pre-processing is the newlines. There are many blank lines between data rows. Some are single blank lines between the data rows, and some are two or more lines. I want to end up with no blank lines between the data rows, but each row will be delineated by a newline character.

**Issue 3:** The final resulting files each need to be tab separated value files, for importing into a spreadsheet. Some of the descriptions in the data rows may contain commas, so I am using TSV rather than CSV files. I only need a single tab between each value in the row.

### Sample rows

(I have replaced spaces with • and newlines with ¶ characters here for clarity.)

```
9415077026340•Pams•Sour•Cream•&•Chives•Rice•Crackers•100g•••$1.19¶
¶
¶
9415077026296•Pams•BBQ•Chicken•Rice•Crackers•100g•••$1.19¶
¶
61424••••••••••••Yoghurt•Raisins•kg•••$23.90/kg¶
¶
9415077036349•Pams•Sliced•Peaches•In•Juice•410g•••$1.29¶
```

### Intended result

(I have also replaced tabs with ⇥ characters here for clarity.)

```
9415077026340⇥Pams•Sour•Cream•&•Chives•Rice•Crackers•100g⇥$1.19¶
9415077026296⇥Pams•BBQ•Chicken•Rice•Crackers•100g⇥$1.19¶
61424⇥Yoghurt•Raisins•kg⇥$23.90/kg¶
9415077036349⇥Pams•Sliced•Peaches•In•Juice•410g⇥$1.29¶
```

### What have I tried?

I am slowly learning more about the various Linux script utilities such as `sed` / `grep` / `awk` / `tr`, etc. There are many solutions posted in StackOverflow which resolve some of the issues that I am facing, but they are disparate and confusing when I attempt to string them all together in the way that I need them. Some are "close, but not quite" solutions, such as replacing all double newlines with a single newline between each data row. I don't need the extra row between them. I have been looking and trying several different options that are close to what I need. It would be helpful if someone could propose a solution which uses a single utility, such as `sed`, to solve all of the issues at once.

Answer (score 0):

Using a perl script you could replace spaces with tabs and remove empty lines in the text file.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use utf8;
use warnings;

#    Save original text as backup

$^I = ".bak";

while ( <> )
{
#   If the line starts with digits...
    if ( /^\d+/ )
    {
    #   Replace the space or spaces after the numbers with a tab.
        s/^(\d+)\s+(\w)/$1\t$2/;
    #   Replace three spaces before the price at the end of the line with a tab.
        s/\s{3}(.+)$/\t$1/;
    #   Save the line.
        print;
    }
}

exit;
```